# Runtime Error - NZEC -Python- Hackerearth

Tags: python-3.x

You have been given an array A of size N consisting of positive integers. You need to find and print the product of all the number in this array Modulo 10 raise to the power 9+7.

How to solve Runtime Error - NZEC in my python code:

```
import sys
mul=[]
f=1
a=int(input())
for i in range(a):mul.append(int(input()))
for i in range(0,a):
    print(mul[i])
    f=f*int(mul[i])
f=f%1000000007
print (f)
```

Comment: If that's how your code is actually formatted, you have multiple issues in lines 5-8.

Comment: ...although I see @demonplus changed your formatting for you, so you might want to look at it and make sure it matches what you have.

Comment: I am sure I didn't break it while formatting :)

Comment: @demonplus I see now, you just added a newline.

Comment: @glibdud Yes, it was completely a mess before

Answer (score 0):

Replace f = f * int(mul[i]) with f=(f * int(mul[i]))%1000000007